# I would like to know how to execute this following python code?

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

```
import argparse

import googleapiclient.discovery


def create_service():

return googleapiclient.discovery.build('storage', 'v1')


def list_buckets(service, project_id):
   buckets = service.buckets().list(project=project_id).execute()
   return buckets


def main(project_id):
  service = create_service()
  buckets = list_buckets(service, project_id)
  print(buckets)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
 parser.add_argument('project_id', help='Your project iD')

 args = parser.parse_args()
 main(args.project_id)
```

#Need to know how to run this example. Since i am new to python. When ever i execute it gives expected to few parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error you see is:

```
usage: your_script.py [-h] project_id
your_script.py: error: too few arguments
```

You need to specify the project ID. So if you were previously running `python your_script.py` you need to run `python your_script.py`*`your-project-id`* instead.